# Datagridview Export HeaderText

Tags: winforms, powershell, datagridview

I'm working with the datagridview below. I'm trying to export the header names.

If you run this code and hit export, it will only output the column headers that the user can see initially (up to 'Model'), but it won't output 'Version' or 'Last Rebooted'. If you scroll to the right before hitting export then it will display all column names.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Windows.Forms”)
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Drawing”)
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1040,518)
$form.KeyPreview = $true
$form.StartPosition = ‘centerscreen’
$form.BackColor = 'MidnightBlue'
$form.Add_KeyDown({if($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape"){$form.Close()}})
$form.Text = "Dialog Box 3.4" 
$form.Icon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($PSHOME + "\powershell_ise.exe")
$form.MinimumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1040,518)

$buttonPanel4 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Panel
$buttonPanel4.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(290,70)
$buttonPanel4.Dock = "left"
$buttonPanel4.BackColor = 'MidnightBlue'

$DataGrid = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$DataGrid.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(298,29)
$DataGrid.Dock = "Fill"
$DataGrid.BorderStyle = ‘FixedSingle’
$DataGrid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“segoe UI”,9.25)
$DataGrid.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“segoe UI”,9.25)
$DataGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = $false
$DataGrid.RowHeadersVisible = $false
$DataGrid.BackgroundColor = "White"

$DataGrid.ColumnCount = 10
$DataGrid.Columns[0].Name = ‘Machine’
$DataGrid.Columns[1].Name = ‘OperatingSystem’
$DataGrid.Columns[2].Name = ‘ServicePack’
$DataGrid.Columns[3].Name = ‘Architecture’
$DataGrid.Columns[4].Name = ‘Domain’
$DataGrid.Columns[5].Name = ‘PhysicalMemory’
$DataGrid.Columns[6].Name = ‘Manufacturer’
$DataGrid.Columns[7].Name = ‘Model’
$DataGrid.Columns[8].Name = ‘Version’
$DataGrid.Columns[9].Name = ‘Last Rebooted’
$DataGrid.Columns[9].Width = '140'

$Exportbutton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Exportbutton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(9,350)
$Exportbutton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(85,23)
$Exportbutton.Text = “Export-CSV”
$Exportbutton.BackColor = ‘LightGray’
$Exportbutton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
$Exportbutton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“segoe UI”,9)
$Exportbutton.Add_Click({
    $columnNames = $null
    $columnNames = $DataGrid.Columns[0].HeaderText
    for($i = 1; $i -lt $DataGrid.ColumnCount;$i++){
        $columnNames += ",$($DataGrid.Columns[$i].HeaderText)"
        write-host $($DataGrid.Columns[$i].HeaderText) -ForegroundColor Magenta
    }
    write-host $columnNames -foregroundcolor cyan
})

$buttonPanel4.Controls.Add($Exportbutton)
$form.Controls.Add($DataGrid)
$form.Controls.Add($buttonPanel4)
$form.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

Is there a reason why this occurs and how can I export all the column names without scrolling to the right first?

Comment: what is variable `$buttonPanel4` ?

Comment: Sorry, I spliced this out of my larger program and forgot to include the panel. It goes on the left and the datagrid on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @pandemic points out, `$buttonPanel4` is not defined/shown, also it appears you are setting the `DataGrid.Dock` property to `Fill`, which would cover up this button if it’s panel existed.

I do not have an answer for WHY the headers text returns an empty string until the header becomes visible in the data grid. I am guessing it is because the `HeaderText` property has not been set. I assume if the `HeaderText`s property has not been set it will default to the columns `Name` property if needed. If you set each columns `HeaderText` property as you are with the `Name` property, this problem will not happen.

So either set each columns `HeaderText` or use its `Name` property as the code below shows.

I changed the code below to use the columns Name instead of the headers text and it appears to work correctly. In addition, I changed how the comma is inserted in to the `$columnNames` string variable to start the loop at index 0. Hope this helps.

```
$Exportbutton.Add_Click({
   $columnNames = $null
   for($i = 0; $i -lt $DataGrid.ColumnCount;$i++){
     $columnNames += "$($DataGrid.Columns[$i].Name)"
     if ($i -lt $DataGrid.ColumnCount - 1) {
       $columnNames += ","
     }
     write-host $($DataGrid.Columns[$i].Name) -ForegroundColor Magenta
   }
   write-host $columnNames -foregroundcolor cyan
})
```

Comment: Your assumption that by referencing `Name` instead of `HeaderText` was correct. When I change it, I am able to get all the column names as I need them. Thank you for your response!